# Encoding.UTF8.GetString converted latin script letters (ç,ã) into question mark while reading byte object

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am sending following query using byte array to machine by uploading the sql file:

```
insert Table (str_udcname) values('Compressão por mola ou expansão');
```

Converting uploaded sql file using following code:

```
 byte[] fileData = null;
 using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
 {
  fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
 }
```

On desktop while I am receiving file using following code:

```
 string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.AttachmentFile.ToArray());
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBContext.GetConnectionstring().ConnectionString);
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(result);
```

While I am trying to get string of this using Encoding.UTF8 it is converted as:

```
insert Table (str_udcname) values('Compress?o por mola ou expans?o');
```

Please let me know How I can get same characters which were uploaded from site.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Plz lemme know if the file is text file?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution using StreamReader, I am able to implement default encoding using following code:

```
 string result = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(item.AttachmentFile.ToArray()), Encoding.Default))
            {

                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.AttachmentFile.ToArray());
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBContext.GetConnectionstring().ConnectionString);
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(result);
```

Comment: You should have a look at File.WriteAllText and File.ReadAllText. Both has Encoding as an optional parameter. The main issue with your code is/was that you did not use the same encoding for writing and reading the text file